# Is it possible to connect two iPhones to the same external GPS device?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, gps

I can connect an iPhone to an external GPS device, but when I use another iPhone to also try to connect to it, it won't connect.

But there are posts that stated [we can connect two iPhones to a single Bluetooth device](https://superuser.com/questions/836966/can-i-pair-multiple-hosts-to-a-single-bluetooth-headphones-device#:%7E:text=As%20it%20turns%20out%2C%20yes,from%20device%20B%20will%20fail.). Does it depend on the Bluetooth device?

It makes sense if the GPS signal can be provided to two iPhones if there are two people hiking together, but maybe it takes extra design steps to make such a Bluetooth device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this depends on the Bluetooth device.

Also note that there's a difference in *pairing* multiple phones with the same device, and actually be *actively using* the device from multiple phones at the same time.

I do not think it is common for Bluetooth devices to allow the latter in this use case, however it is ofcourse possible to implement for the device maker (at the extreme including two separate Bluetooth modules).